# What does activation energy actually do?

Tags: energy, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential

Spontaneous (exothermic) chemical reactions often require a push from the addition of externally supplied energy. This energy is often called [activation energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_energy). What does activation energy actually do? What is the energy hill that the activation energy surmounts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It essentially is the energy required to start breaking up the molecules involved. This happens through collisions. So, the activation energy is a measure of the amount of heat (via temperature, which is a measure of translational energy of molecules) required for the collisions to start breaking things up when they hit.

For instance, $\mathrm{CH_4}$ and $\mathrm{O_2}$ at $200\,\rm K$ won't really react. This is because the translational energy is too low; when an $\mathrm{O_2}$ hits a $\mathrm{CH_4}$, energy is exchanged but not enough to break the bond in $\mathrm{CH_4}$ or $\mathrm{O_2}$.

The form of energy transfer is also important. It can enter different modes: translational-translational, translational-rotational, translational-vibrational, etc. It's the T-V collisions that matter. Once enough energy is transferred from translational energy to vibrational energy, the bonds snap and reactions occur.