# How does the concept of activation energy work for interatomic collisions?

Tags: atomic-physics, collision, molecules, quantum-chemistry

Say we have a Lennard-Jones -esque potential for colliding atoms. Say this potential admits a bound state at a lower energy than the kinetic energy of the colliding atoms. So forming this molecule would be an exothermic reaction.

Do the colliding atoms always form this bound state? That seems wrong to me, as I remember there is such a concept of activation energy. But for these basic interatomic potentials, there doesn't seem to be any potential barrier to overcome.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If there's electron transfer between the atoms, ionization energy could be a factor.

Comment: [See this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164426/119186)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20907/260477